# Android Project is not runnable which new created in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I try to run a android project which i created new ,

[image]

i can not run it because when i right click project --> RUN AS --> RUN CONFIGURATIONS .  There is no my project under 'Android Applications' on purpose run it !

[image]

i just updated a few things and Android 5.0 (API LEVEL 21) from  SDK Manager .

Please Help !

Comment: There is a "new" (blank page symbol+) icon there on the top left. have you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

their is a browse button in Run Configuration window.click it and select your project and run